# Need ACPI = off to boot

Tags: boot, 19.10

I installed a USB Live Ubuntu 19.10 this week. At first when I tried to shut down the system, it gives an Pcie Bus Error.So I use "PCI = nomsi". It worked only once. Then it gives a new error : "nouveau : tmr : stalled at ffffffff" .I found "acpi = off" can slove the problem but my laptop needs power detection and wifi. So how can I do? HELP!

(please excuse that I can't speak English well, thx :)

Comment: You don`t have to use acpi=off if you can boot into Ubuntu without any problem. You can use other options such as noapic, nonconfig=sudo, vga=788, or acpi=force or acpi=oldboot options.

Comment: thx :)  I know what problem there was.

Comment: You can add the answer to your Question. Or how you solved it, so that some else might resolves such a problem too with your answer.